# Laravel Relationships | Joins | Eloquents - Looking for a better way to write this Query -

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Lets suppose, I have two tables which are `customers` and `leads`.

Car table has these columns `id, name, phone, source` while leads table has `id, customer_id (FK) and other columns`.

I want to fetch `count of leads` against each `source`. Here is my query and it works just fine!

```
Customer::leftJoin('leads', 'leads.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->select('customers.source', DB::raw('count(leads.id) as source_leads_count'))
    ->whereBetween('customers.created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->groupBy('customers.source')
    ->orderBy('source_leads_count', 'DESC')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

My above query works fine and it returns me an array.

```
[
    {
        "source": "facebook",
        "source_leads_count": 1300
    },
    {
        "source": "google",
        "source_leads_count": 600,
    },
]
```

I am looking forward to do this query with Laravel eloquent relationships if it is possible. I have tried some relationships but none of them work.

Comment: Seems like you only need one relationship. Show us what you've tried (even if it doesn't work) and any errors that show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$customer= Customer::withCount('leads')->get();
```

if you need a more complex query it will look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$customer= Customer::withCount(['leads' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->orderBy('name');
}])->get();
```

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models